# How can I see JavaScript function documentation (anything about the function) in Atom?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I have just installed Jest using npm and I have the following in my code editor in Atom:

[image: code]

I am assuming that the test function is available because I have installed Jest. But how can I see that this is the case?  How can I view information about where functions are being called from?  Let's say I have a foo function in more than one library/package/module (I am still learning js so I am hazarding guesses here).  How can I tell where a particular foo is being picked up from?  I have installed Atom Tern JS but it isn't helping. 
Coming from other IDEs like Eclipse, etc. this apparently total lack of information on what is getting called is quite disconcerting.

I'm using Atom 1.31.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: well, you need debugger. Not sure how this works with atom, but `vscode` comes with one as default.

Comment: Thanks but presumably a debugger is for debugging running code. I am writing the code at this point.

Comment: currently your `test` function is defined globally. The injection would happen when you run a command `jest` from cmd. You can force to import method in scope by `import {test} from 'jest'`. Even in other IDE wouldn't be possible to say where the method comes from before running command. Let say I overwrite jest test method by my own and inject it in command on `npm run test`. However in `npm run original-test` I would use original test method. There is no way any IDE would catch that properly without explicit import

Comment: OK. I am not familiar with npm run test etc. I have added `import {test, expect, it } from 'jest';` to my file as you mentioned/suggested and that at least stops jshint warning about the functions not being defined.  I can see that TernJS is working for built-in stuff eg Math.random.  I think its possible it needs to be configured for each and every project before it can be used. Not sure. Thanks.

Comment: well, you are currenly not working on project level. You are on file level and thats why you hitting the issues. You need to configure `ternjs` https://github.com/khezer/tern-jest and jshint (I'm pretty sure you should use eslint here). Because you are new, I recommend to try some of examples with jest from official repo https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples. Just download/clone the repository go to example and run `npm install`